# Yet another EXC_BAD_ACCESS - However with zombie (instruments), never exe_bad_access

Tags: objective-c, xcode, memory-management, nsstring, exc-bad-access

I have spent hours on this and read everybit on the web about memory management, zombies. leaks (tried instruments). But I cannot figure this one out. Does someone has a clue? I am getting a EXC_BAD_ACCESS at the following like of code on popping the ChildViewController.

```
[profileVO release]; profileVO = nil;
```

I strongly feel I have followed all memory management best practices!

**Details:**

I have a model file. (CachedProfileVO)

**CachedProfileVO.h**

```
@interface CachedProfileVO : NSObject {

   NSString *name;
   NSString *email;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *email;

@end
```

**CachedProfileVO.m**

```
@synthesize name, email;
- (void) dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
    [name release]; name= nil;
    [email release]; email = nil; 
}
```

Now I have a UINavigationController. The ParentViewController and the ChildViewController.
I invoke the ChildViewController as follows:

```
[self.navigationCntroller pushViewcontroller:childViewcontroller animated:YES];
```

In the ChildViewController, I basically use the model CachedProfileVO. However when this view controller is popped (back button on UI), it gives a EXC_BAD_ACCESS

**ChildViewController.h**

```
@interface ChildViewcontroller : UITableViewController {
    CachedProfileVO *profileVO;  

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) CachedProfileVO *profileVO;
@end
```

**ChildViewController.m**

```
@synthesize profileVO;

- (void) dealloc
{
   [super dealloc];
   [profileVO release]; profileVO = nil; ****** GETTING EXE_BAD_ACCESS here
}

- (void) viewDidLoad
{
 CachedProfileVO *vo = [CachedProfileVO alloc] init];
 self.profileVO = vo;
 [vo release];

}

//responseString looks like this: [Murdoch, murdoch@email.com][other data][more data]
- (void) populateProfile:(NSString *) responseString 
{
  NSMutableString *str = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithCapacity:20];
  [str setString:responseString];
  [str deleteCharactersInRange: NSMakeRange(0,1)];
  [str deleteCharactersInRange: NSMakeRange([str length]-1,1)];
  NSArray *tempArray = [str componentsSeparatedByString: @"]["];

  NSString *tempStr = (NSString*)[tempArray objectAtIndex:0];
  NSArray *bioArray = [tempStr componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

  self.profileVO.name = (NSString*)[bioArray objectAtIndex:0];
  self.profileVO.email= (NSString*)[bioArray objectAtIndex:1];

  [str release]; str = nil;
}
```

Note that the function populateProfile is called after some event. I know it is called. And dealloc then causes the problem. Also this does not happen in every pop. I have to try several times to reproduce. It is never reproduced using zombies in instruments!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `[super dealloc];` first in your examples. That should always be the last call otherwise you are accessing instance variables that belong to a now deallocated class. The following should work fine if you followed memory management rules elsewhere.

```
- (void) dealloc
{
   [profileVO release];

   [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: Whoa! I have seen so many examples with [super dealloc] as the first statement. Even in apple examples. And till today I have done that. Never had any issue. Not sure why with this example this started happening. But moving [super dealloc] to end solved the issue. Also anyone cares to explain why with NSZombie it never crashes?

Comment: I have learned to not depend on Apple examples for learning best practices. I have seen terrible practices used and even some that have warnings. The reason why zombies may not have been crashing it is because it was allowing the instance variables to still be valid long enough for you to release them.

Comment: thanks joe. Ya the nszombie thing is bit confusing. Though it is a great tool, one should never trust a tool too much specially when it comes to memory. Who knows what fancy thing it is doing behind the scenes like not releasing objects. I am sure they HAVE to do it to function. But that kinda beats the purpose.

Comment: If you see *any* examples with `[super dealloc]` as the first line in an Apple example **file a bug**.